# Formcontrolname not appending dynamically in angular

Tags: angular

Iam using Angular reactive form and in html looping through array of objects binding dynamic name to formcontrolname,when I inspect for form control name on input it is not showing.

And when I submit form by entering values in input field the frmgrp.value with empty values,
please help to rectify issue

```
 <form [formGroup]="frmGroup"> 
 <div *ngFor="let form_elem of formtemplate">
 <div [ngSwitchCase]="form_elem.keyType">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'TEXTBOX'"> 
   <div class="col-lg-4">
    <label for="{{form_elem.keyName}}" class="col-form-label"> 
    {form_elem.keyName}}</label>                                        
     <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" 
     formControlName="form_elem.keyName"                                  
          id="{{form_elem.keyName}}">                                    
         </div>
          </div>
           </form>
  if(this.formtemplate.length>0){
  this.formtemplate.forEach((val:any) => {
    val.keyName=val.keyName.replace(/\s/g, "");
  });
 this.formtemplate.forEach((val:any)=>{
   group[val.keyName]=new FormControl('');  
 });
 group['id']=new FormControl('');  
 this.frmGroup = this.fb.group({group})
 this.frmGroup.controls=this.frmGroup.controls.group.value;
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code as code blocks instead of writing a comment.

Comment: @Akhil, write `[formControlName]="form_elem.keyName"`. In Angular if you use the "binding" `[` `]` makes that the part indicate between quotes was a the value of a variable.

Comment: so  @Eliseo how should i change formcontrolname to get dynamic value,i changed that value like this formControlName="{{form_elem.keyName}}" ,still it is not working

Comment: I don't know about your frmGroup nor your formtemplate (be sure you has no a type error -in your code you has `form template`  and `form Group` (with a space between and sure you need remove the space). BTW. write `<pre>{{frmGroup?.value|json}} {{formTemplate|json}}</pre>` in the .html to see the values of the variables

Comment: sorry @eliso i made mistake here,but there is no space between formgroup and form template

Comment: make a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: Can you update and share the contents of the TS file?

Comment: @Akhil Can you show your typescript code where you build your formGroup ?

Comment: if(this.formtemplate.length>0){
      this.formtemplate.forEach((val:any) => {
        val.keyName=val.keyName.replace(/\s/g, "");
      });
     this.formtemplate.forEach((val:any)=>{
       group[val.keyName]=new FormControl('');  
     });
     group['id']=new FormControl('');  
     this.frmGroup = this.fb.group({group})
     this.frmGroup.controls=this.frmGroup.controls.group.value;
    }          Please check this

Comment: @Akhil, you should use addControl: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl like AJT82 show in this answer

Answer (score 0):

You have many errors, I don't even know how your template would compile. The ngSwitch is wrongly implemented, you are missing a `{` on the label and `formControlName="form_elem.keyName"` should be `[formControlName]="form_elem.keyName"` as you are binding a variable.

The TS looks pretty good, the big no-no is here:

```
this.frmGroup.controls = this.frmGroup.controls.group.value;
```

You are assigning a regular javascript object to the formgroup. You cannot do that, they are no form controls, just a simple javascript object.

`group` seems to hold all your form controls, so you can use the spread operator to add them to your form... NOW you have a formgroup with form controls. But you really don't need `group`, just add the controls directly to your formgroup.

Taking in consideration everything I have mentioned, your code should look something like this:

```ts
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  if (this.formtemplate.length) {
    this.frmGroup = this.fb.group({})
    this.formtemplate.forEach((val: any) => {
      this.frmGroup.addControl(val.keyName, this.fb.control(''));
    })
  }
}
```

Template:

```html
<form [formGroup]="frmGroup" *ngIf="frmGroup">
  <div *ngFor="let form_elem of formtemplate">
    <div [ngSwitch]="form_elem.keyType">
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'TEXTBOX'">
        <label>{{form_elem.keyName}}</label>
        <input type="text" [formControlName]="form_elem.keyName">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Also, **don't** use `any`. Type your data, we are using **Type**Script ;)

A **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n5sskd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** for your reference